# watermark Text-box Align Center

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using custom control `watermark textbox` and it's perfect, but the problem is that I can't change the watermark textAlign to center or right to left.
By default it's left to right, how can I make it center or right to left?

This is the code :

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Watermark
Inherits TextBox

'Declare A Few Variables
Dim WaterText As String
Dim WaterColor As Color
Dim WaterFont As Font
Dim WaterBrush As SolidBrush
Dim WaterContainer As Panel

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    StartProcess()
End Sub

Private Sub StartProcess()
    'Assign Values To the Variables
    WaterText = "Default Watermark"
    WaterColor = Color.Gray
    WaterFont = New Font(Me.Font, FontStyle.Italic)
    WaterBrush = New SolidBrush(WaterColor)

    CreateWatermark()

    AddHandler TextChanged, AddressOf ChangeText
    AddHandler FontChanged, AddressOf ChangeFont
End Sub

Private Sub CreateWatermark()
    WaterContainer = New Panel
    Me.Controls.Add(WaterContainer)
    AddHandler WaterContainer.Click, AddressOf Clicked
    AddHandler WaterContainer.Paint, AddressOf Painted
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveWatermark()
    Me.Controls.Remove(WaterContainer)
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeText(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Me.TextLength <= 0 Then
        CreateWatermark()
    ElseIf Me.TextLength > 0 Then
        RemoveWatermark()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeFont(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    WaterFont = New Font(Me.Font, FontStyle.Italic)
End Sub

Private Sub Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Painted(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
    WaterContainer.Location = New Point(2, 0)
    WaterContainer.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Right
    WaterContainer.Height = Me.Height
    WaterContainer.Width = Me.Width
    WaterBrush = New SolidBrush(WaterColor)

    Dim Graphic As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Graphic.DrawString(WaterText, WaterFont, WaterBrush, New PointF(-2.0!, 1.0!))
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnInvalidated(e As System.Windows.Forms.InvalidateEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnInvalidated(e)
    WaterContainer.Invalidate()
End Sub

<Category("Watermark Attributes"), Description("Sets Watermark Text")> Public Property WatermarkText As String
    Get
        Return WaterText
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        WaterText = value
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property

<Category("Watermark Attributes"), Description("Sets Watermark Color")> Public Property WatermarkColor As Color
    Get
        Return WaterColor
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
        WaterColor = value
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to note:

- There is already a mechanism for this in Windows called a `CueBanner` which is very easy to implement either from form code or as a custom control
- Your implementation doesn't quite behave or look the same as the Native implementation:
  a) there is no visual cue (TB Cursor) until you hide the `Panel`
  b) Your Panel/Cue Text doesn't disappear until you start typing.  This seems to be what you want, but it is not how the native one typically works (as Visual Vincent points out in a comment, there is an option for this. I personally cant recall seeing it enough to register with me).
  c) In the native implementation, the Cue Text/Watermark uses the same font as the control.  Only a `Combobox` set to `DropDownList` uses Italic (maybe you never noticed this).
- Your app is leaking pretty badly in spots: `CreateWatermark` gets called repeatedly to redisplay the Watermark/CueText by creating a new `Panel` each time, but you are not disposing of the old one.  Remember: **If you create a control in code, you also need to dispose of it** rather than just removing it from the controls collection.
- The same is true for the `Font` object, although that will only matter if the `Font` on the TextBox changes.

First, an answer to the question you asked - allowing Left, Right, Center TextAlignment.

```
Private Sub Painted(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
    ' this can all be moved to the CreateWatermark method
    'WaterContainer.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    'WaterContainer.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Right
    'WaterContainer.Height = Me.Height
    'WaterContainer.Width = Me.Width

    Dim rect As New Rectangle(2, 1, Width - 8, Height - 2)
    Dim TxtFlags As TextFormatFlags
    Select Case TxtAlign
        Case HorizontalAlignment.Center
            TxtFlags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter
        Case HorizontalAlignment.Left
            TxtFlags = TextFormatFlags.Left
        Case HorizontalAlignment.Right
            TxtFlags = TextFormatFlags.Right
    End Select

    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, WatermarkText, WFont, rect, WatermarkColor, TxtFlags)
End Sub
```

- This uses the `TextRenderer` for drawing the text which is usually a better choice for controls (save `Graphics.DrawString()` for drawing to bitmaps and images)
- This version shows it based on a new `WatermarkTextAlign` property in case you want to allow it to vary from the `TextBox`.  If not, use parts of Visual Vincent's version or combine them.

---

#### Cue Banner

```
Partial Friend Class NativeMethods
    ...
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Friend Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, msg As Integer,
                                       wParam As Integer,
                                       <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> lParam As String) As Int32
    End Function

    Private Const EM_SETCUEBANNER As Integer = &H1501
    Private Const CB_SETCUEBANNER As Int32 = &H1703

    Friend Shared Sub SetCueText(ctl As Control, text As String)

        If TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox Then
            SendMessage(ctl.Handle, CB_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text)
        Else
            SendMessage(ctl.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Usage is simple:

```
NativeMethods.SetCueText(tbPInvWM, "Enter text...")
NativeMethods.SetCueText(ComboBox1, "Select...")
```

You can also create a control which inherits from TextBox and implement it there (override `OnHandleCreated`).  This would allow the Cue Text to show at design time as your does, but with much less code.

---

Finally, there is an easier way to do it with an internal control:

- Rather than a `Panel`, use a `Label`.  You can use the label's `Font`, `TextAlign`, `ForeColor` and `Text` properties as the backing fields for the Properties you expose.  The `RightToLeft` setting could also be mirrored.
- To make the Watermark/Cue Text/Label disappear as needed, just set it to invisible

This would **eliminate all issues related to disposing and drawing the text**.

```
Public Class TextBoxEx
    Inherits TextBox

    Private WaterCtrl As Label

    ...
    ' Example of using label props as the backing field:
   <Category("Watermark Attributes"),
     Description("Sets Watermark Text"),
     DefaultValue("Watermark Text")>
        Public Property WatermarkText As String
        Get
            If WaterCtrl IsNot Nothing Then
                Return WaterCtrl.Text
            Else
                Return ""
            End If
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If WaterCtrl IsNot Nothing Then
                WaterCtrl.Text = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
```

The Cue Text display is handled by making the label visible or not:

```
' when they click on the label, hide and
' activate the TB like a regular CueBanner does
Private Sub LblClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    WaterCtrl.Visible = False
    Me.Select()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnLeave(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLeave(e)
    WaterCtrl.Visible = (Text.Length = 0)
End Sub
```

Thats not all the code, but it should give you a start and it's both simpler and acts more like the native version.

Comment: thank you for your answer, your answer very handy, but I'm already in project that I worked on it for month until now and i don't want
to do the watermark textboxes again, your answer for my code was perfect, but is there a way to make the watermark font smaller than the actual font ?
and about  Visual Vincent code, the water mark not shown.

Comment: `WaterFont = New Font(Me.Font.Name, Me.Font.SizeInPoints - 2, FontStyle.Italic)`  or use a fixed value.  The issues related to leaks is **not** something you should ignore - eventually you will run out of resources.  The 3rd version - the replace Panel with Label - is much simpler way to do what you are doing - no need to draw or dispose anything

Comment: I have a comment about this in your answer: `b) Your Panel/Cue Text doesn't disappear until you start typing. This seems to be what you want, but it is not how the native one works.` - Infact the native one _**does**_ have the option to operate that way. See [**this documentation article**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639(v=vs.85).aspx): _"wParam - **TRUE** if the cue banner should show **even when the edit control has focus**; otherwise, FALSE. **FALSE** is the default behavior—the cue banner **disappears when the user clicks in the control**"_.

Comment: @VisualVincent I didnt know that option was there...and it works.  However I cant recall seeing that behavior in WinForms.  Web inputs everywhere seem to persist until you type - I am forever trying to select and delete the cue.  They also seem to use a darker color making it seem like text not a cue...at least to my crappy eyes

Comment: Heh. Well it's not WinForms, but Windows 7's built-in Remote Desktop application (RDP) uses this behaviour (I don't know about Windows 8-10 since I don't have them).

Answer (score 1):

You set the watermark's position every time it is painted. You just have to check the TextBox's properties and determine where to place the watermark (however you must do so after you set the watermark's size).

You would also have to set the watermark's width to the width of the actual watermark text or else you won't be able to do any alignment.

```
Private Sub Painted(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
    WaterContainer.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Right
    WaterContainer.Height = Me.Height

    'Declare a variable indicating whether RightToLeft is set or not.
    Dim RightToLeft As Boolean = (Me.RightToLeft = Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes)

    'Set the watermark's client width according to the text's width.
    Dim MeasuredTextSize As Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(WaterText, WaterFont, Me.Size, If(RightToLeft, TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft, TextFormatFlags.Default))
    WaterContainer.ClientSize = New Size(MeasuredTextSize.Width, WaterContainer.ClientSize.Height)

    'Determine the watermark's alignment.
    If (Me.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left AndAlso RightToLeft = False) OrElse (Me.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right AndAlso RightToLeft = True) Then
        WaterContainer.Location = New Point(2, 0) 'Left alignment, or right alignment with RightToLeft set.

    ElseIf Me.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center Then
        WaterContainer.Location = New Point((Me.Width / 2) - (WaterContainer.Width / 2), 0) 'Center alignment.

    ElseIf (Me.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right AndAlso RightToLeft = False) OrElse (Me.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left AndAlso RightToLeft = True) Then
        WaterContainer.Location = New Point((Me.Width - WaterContainer.Width) - 2, 0) 'Right alignment, or left alignment with RightToLeft set.

    End If

    WaterBrush = New SolidBrush(WaterColor)

    Dim Graphic As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Graphic.DrawString(WaterText, WaterFont, WaterBrush, New PointF(-2.0! + If(RightToLeft, MeasuredTextSize.Width, 0), 1.0!), New StringFormat(CType(If(RightToLeft, StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft, 0), Integer)))
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this code give me error in the last line:  `Graphic.DrawString(WaterText, WaterFont, WaterBrush, New PointF(-2.0!, 1.0!), New StringFormat(If(Me.RightToLeft, 0)))`
the error here : `Me.RightToLeft`
the error is : `First Operated in binary'If' expression must be nullable or reference type.`

Comment: @Rabeeaqabaha : Sorry about that, made a little code mistake. Edited the answer.

Comment: the code now without errors, but unfortunately the watermark text disappear now :(.

Comment: @Rabeeaqabaha : Have you tried different kinds of settings? The alignment of the watermark should differ depending on the TextBox's `TextAlign` and `RightToLeft` properties. I'll try this later when I get the time, but I'm afraid I can't do so right now (I wrote the answer from my phone).

Comment: `I wrote the answer from my phone` Ahh! When you get to an IDE, you'll see that `RightToLeft` is an Enum {yes, No, Inherit} not a boolean

Comment: @Plutonix : Oooh... I usually check the documentation for every property/class/etc. that I use when I write from my phone, but this time I felt quite certain that `RightToLeft` was a boolean! Still though, that doesn't explain why it isn't shown at all... Thanks a lot! I have access to an IDE in a few minutes.

Comment: I started to work on it out of curiousity and because I didnt think to consider RightToLeft in my answer, but ultimately using a Label there isnt a need to draw anything

Comment: @Plutonix : You're certainly right about that! And docking it in the `TextBox` is the easiest thing to do as it would only require you to modify its `TextAlign` property. -- I thought I'd help the OP modify his current code since the question askers don't always want to change their way of doing things once they've managed to achieve it themselves.

Comment: @Rabeeaqabaha : Glad you found a solution! For what it's worth I have now tested and fixed the code in my answer.

Comment: @Visual Vincent , thank you a lot I'm so grateful for your help, I'll try your answer :).