# Visual Basics Watermark passwordchar?

Tags: vb.net, authentication, watermark

I'm currently making a login form to my program where I have a watermark for the two textboxes Email and Password.

When a textbox is empty, its watermark text will appear in it like "Username" and "Password".
My code is: 
Public Class frmLogin

```
Private Sub TextBox2_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        TextBox2.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
        TextBox2.Text = "Username"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.GotFocus
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox2.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        TextBox2.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
        TextBox2.Text = "Username"
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
        TextBox1.Text = "Password"
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

But now my problem is that I want to use password characters for the password. But I still want the watermark text to be in regular text. When I check to use a password char it turns my watermark into "**" instead of "Password". How can I fix that?

Comment: You are recreating the wheel - [Cue Banner Text](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41491609/1070452) is built into windows and works independent of the text property.  otherwise set PasswordChar on Enter and Leave

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems good:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles  TextBox1.GotFocus
         Textbox1.PasswordChar = "*"
         Textbox1.Clear()
End Sub


Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus
         TextBox1.PasswordChar = ControlChars.NullChar
End Sub
```