# How to set the Text of a TextBox to a default value

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I maybe can't explain this problem properly but let's say that my TextBox has a Text inside "MM/DD/YYYY" that was edited on its Properties. I want to know how will the TextBox go back to that Text again once it was not selected. I tried coding it for once the TextBox is Click the Text will clear itself but I want to know how will it go back to that Text again. Sorry my English sucks but hope you understand.

```
 Private Sub birthdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles birthdate.Click
    birthdate.Clear()
End Sub
```

Here's the code when I click the TextBox it will clear the Text itself. This will give you idea of what I'm saying

Comment: There are various examples about of custom `TextBox` controls that add that functionality. [Here](https://www.mking.net/blog/cue-banners-in-winforms) is one in C# that can be easily converted to VB. I would suggest installing [this](https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/product_details/csharp-to-vb-converter.html) to do the conversion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [watermark Text-box Align Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485621/watermark-text-box-align-center). See accepted answer for all the detail you need to enable the Cue Banner feature on Windows platforms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Placeholder in TextBox in Window Forms using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924572/placeholder-in-textbox-in-window-forms-using-vb-net)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Watermark TextBox in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms)

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension module that adds a method, to both TextBox and ComboBox Controls, that activates the Cue Banner<sup>1</sup> internal functionality. For the TextBox, in the two available flavors: the Cue Banner is visible: **a)** until the control gets focus, **b)** after the first char is entered.
The ComboBox control removes the Cue Banner as soon as it receives focus or the `DropDown` is opened.

The Win32 function [SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) is used modify the behavior of the `Edit` control - the TextBox control and the `Edit` child control of a ComboBox, sending the [`EM_SETCUEBANNER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setcuebanner) and [`CB_SETCUEBANNER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-setcuebanner) messages, respectively.

> <sup>1</sup> <sub>Sets the textual cue, or tip, that is displayed by
> the edit control to prompt the user for information.</sub>

---

Since these are extension methods, each method *extends* the controls functionality and can be called directly:

```
' The Cue Banner is visible until the control gets focus
TextBox1.SetCueBanner("MM/DD/YYYY", False)

' The Cue Banner is visible until a character is entered
TextBox1.SetCueBanner("User Name...", True)

ComboBox1.SetCueBanner("Select an item...")
```

---

Add a Module to the Project and substitute the code generated by the template with this:

**VB.Net version:**

```
Public Module ModExtentions

    Private Const EM_SETCUEBANNER As Integer = &H1501
    Private Const CB_SETCUEBANNER As Integer = &H1703

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As String) As Integer
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Sub SetCueBanner(tbox As TextBox, ByVal text As String, ByVal showOnFocus As Boolean)
        If tbox.IsHandleCreated Then SendMessage(tbox.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, If(showOnFocus, 1, 0), text)
    End Sub

    <Extension()>
    Public Sub SetCueBanner(cbo As ComboBox, ByVal text As String)
        If cbo.IsHandleCreated Then SendMessage(cbo.Handle, CB_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text)
    End Sub
End Module
```

**C# Version:**

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class ExtControls
{
    private const int EM_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1501;
    private const int CB_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1703;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, string lParam);

    public static void SetCueBanner(this TextBox tbox, string text, bool showOnFocus) {
        if (tbox.IsHandleCreated) {
            SendMessage(tbox.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, showOnFocus ? 1 : 0, text);
        }
    }

    public static void SetCueBanner(this ComboBox cbo, string text) {
        if (cbo.IsHandleCreated) {
            SendMessage(cbo.Handle, CB_SETCUEBANNER, 0, text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `IsHandleCreated` should be checked before accessing the `Handle`.

Comment: @Loathing I can agree with that. Code updated.